# UWP Video Intro Screen

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on trying to get a video to play when opening a C# UWP. I've tried loading a media element onto a second page and then close that page when the video is ended. The issue I've had is when calling the second page using something like:

```
secondPage.Show();
```

Once the second window would show, then the media would begin playing, but then it won't jump back to my first page after playing the video. I've tried using the current state to keep the second window open while the video is playing using a while loop, but then it makes my first window unresponsive once the second closes. I'm not used to threading, but it sounds like maybe that's going to be the best option here?  Or is there a better way to do this? Essentially what I'm looking for is a video splash screen type thing.

Comment: Try using `Popup` or `ContentDialog` instead of a whole new page.

Comment: Just create MediaPlayerElement at the most top view, set Autoplay to true, subscribe to Ended event and collpase visibility when it's fired.

Comment: @Laith  so you would stay on the Main Page to do it instead of making a frame on the Main Page and then making a second page with the video on it and put it into the content of the main frame?

Comment: What is your `secondPage`? There is no `Show` method for a [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) class in UWP. Could you share the code you are using now?

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT What I am doing is making a frame on the MainPage and naming it with 
    x:Name="Main" then doing a Main.Content = new Page2(); and loading that page into the frame on the main page.

Comment: @gergalern, yes I would keep it all on the same page. Use the popup to display the video as an overlay and then close it when done.